# What should I do to round the edges on my search box?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am a newby coder, so forgive me for asking what is probably a stupid question. For some reason, I was able to round the edges on the search button, but cannot successfully round the edges of the search bar.

[click here to see image of navbar im working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BAcW.png)

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CgSearch } from 'react-icons/cg';
import { BsFillPersonFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { FiMail } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FaPlus } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiTwotoneBell } from 'react-icons/ai';
import './navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
  return (

    <section className="search-bar">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg mx-auto"> 

          <form>
            <div>
              <div className="input-group">
                <div className="homeBtn">
                <h3>VIZZEY</h3> 
                </div> 
              
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search" className="form-control" />
                <button className="searchBtn"><CgSearch /></button>
                <div className="input-group-append buttons">
                
                  
                  <div className="icon">
                    <button className="icon-btn">
                      <h4><FiMail /></h4>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon">
                    <button className="icon-btn">
                      <h4><FaPlus /></h4>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon">
                    <button className="icon-btn">
                      <h4><AiTwotoneBell /></h4>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon">
                    <button className="icon-btn">
                      <h4><BsFillPersonFill /></h4>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default Navbar;
```

Navbar.css

```
.searchBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ff9d;
    height: 38px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    width: 40px;   
    border: black; 
}    

form {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon {
    /* border-radius: 20px;  */
    padding-right: 20px;
} 

.form-control {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); 
border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);  

} 

.form-control:focus-within {
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); 
    border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133); 
    outline: none;  
 
}

.search-bar {
    width: auto; 
    border: solid  #1c1f29; 
    background-color: #1c1f29; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon-btn {
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #00ff9d;
    color: white; 
    outline-color: chocolate;
}

.homeBtn {
    padding-right: 60px; 
    padding-left: 50px; 
    color: #00ff9d;  
 
} 

.buttons {
    padding-left: 55px; 
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Can anybody play around with it and make the left side round life the right side? I thought it would be as simple as adding "border-top-left-radius: 5px" and "border-bottom-left-radius: 5px" to ".form-control" in CSS, since that's the class that controls the search bar. But it isn't changing anything.

Also...
bonus points if you can also get the border around buttons on the right removed to look like the search button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-cx6j4j?file=style.css) with the modification.

I simply removed the border by adding `border: none;` on the `icon-btn` class. For the input, you had to make your property important as follow :

```
.my-input {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: You are the bomb. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome dude :) Feel free to check it as accepted answer if it is ok for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just add this line to the item StyleSheet

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

if you want a diferent radius in each border this is the code

```
border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, you need to add the class `rounded-left` .
so your input becomes : `<input type="search" placeholder="Search" className="form-control rounded-left" />`

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-radius
>
> **Border-radius**
>
> Add classes to an element to easily round its corners.

plain HTML/bootstrap example from your code :

```css
.searchBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ff9d;
    height: 38px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    width: 40px;   
    border: black; 
}    

form {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon {
    /* border-radius: 20px;  */
    padding-right: 20px;
} 

.form-control {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); 
border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);  

} 

.form-control:focus-within {
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); 
    border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133); 
    outline: none;  
 
}

.search-bar {
    width: auto; 
    border: solid  #1c1f29; 
    background-color: #1c1f29; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon-btn {
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #00ff9d;
    color: white; 
    outline-color: chocolate;
}

.homeBtn {
    padding-right: 60px; 
    padding-left: 50px; 
    color: #00ff9d;  
 
} 

.buttons {
    padding-left: 55px; 
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="search-bar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg mx-auto">
      <form>
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="homeBtn">
              <h3>VIZZEY</h3>
            </div>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control rounded-left" />
            <button class="searchBtn"><CgSearch /></button>
            <div class="input-group-append buttons">

              <div class="icon">
                <button class="icon-btn">
                      <h4><FiMail /></h4>
                    </button>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <button class="icon-btn">
                      <h4><FaPlus /></h4>
                    </button>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <button class="icon-btn">
                      <h4><AiTwotoneBell /></h4>
                    </button>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <button class="icon-btn">
                      <h4><BsFillPersonFill /></h4>
                    </button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```